# How to read SQL files and execute it where the sql files are listed on checkList Box?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string, streamreader

I need to execute my sql scripts which are listed on the checklistbox. How i will read the SQL scripts from checklistbox every checklistbox and put it on 
 SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand( "SCRIPT", con); 

feel free to edit the code and help me Thanks! :)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=myDatabase;User Id=sa;Password = Password; ";

foreach (Object item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    try
    {
      using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(checkedListBox1.Items))
      {
        string s = "";
        while ((s = reader.ReadToEnd()) != null)
        {                               
           SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
    }

    con.Open();                 
}
```

Comment: you are creating a SqlCommand but not executing it.

Comment: yup and how will i execute it also?

Comment: look at the SqlCommand class document. you need to write "sql.ExecuteNoneQuery" or "sql.Execute", based on your sql statements

Comment: where I need to put it or insert?
Can u please revise the snippet. please? It will be a great help.

Comment: You need to loop through the selected items of the checklistbox, open each file in turn, read in the SQL from that file, *then* execute it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why would you use a streamreader to get the values from a checkedlistbox. After you populated your checkedlistbox you could try this code to execute the sql commands which are the checked items in your checkedlistbox.

```
 // adding sql commands to your checkedlistbox:
checkedListBox1.Items.Add("SELECT * FROM Table_1");

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=myDatabase;User Id=sa;Password = Password; ";


            string str = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
                {
                    str = (string)checkedListBox1.Items[i];
                    textBox1.Text = str;

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

**This will execute all the sql commands in you checkedlistbox, as long as they are checked.**

Comment: I have a question. Why I have this "SELECT * FROM Table_1". My SQL commands are in SQL files which are listed in checklistbox.